# javascript/php replace image source dynamically from database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, database

I'm working on some code and trying to implement a fluid image grid and doing this with the query plugin called #Freewall.
This works fine so far but now I'm trying (already for a few hrs) to tweak the script a little to pull the images out of a mysql database.
I actually got a part of this to work as well, but the problem is that only the first image gets rendered a few times.
I can't get my head around how to do the while loop correctly – help would be appreciated.

```
/* These two original script code lines (below inside the comment) that replaced the background image inside the background-image attribute, pulled the image from the images folder and counted +1 – that works if images are named 1.jpg/2.jpg/3.jpg/... inside the images folder


var temp = "<div class='cell' style='width:{width}px; height: {height}px; background-image: url(images/{index}.jpg)'></div>";
html += temp.replace(/\{height\}/g, 200).replace(/\{width\}/g, w).replace("{index}", i + 1);


I edited those two lines (and included the php part) but it doesn't loop through the images, it only pulls the first image from the db and renders that 9 times which is the correct limit in the code below  */

$img_sql="SELECT imglinks.artikelID, imglinks.mediasrc FROM imglinks JOIN stock ON imglinks.artikelID=stock.artikelID WHERE imglinks.artikelID=".$artIDclean; if($img_query=mysqli_query($dbconnect, $img_sql)) { $img_rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($img_query); }

   <script type="text/javascript">
        <?php do {
        ?>
                var temp= "<div class='cell' style='width:{width}px; height: {height}px; background-image: url(<?php echo $img_rs['mediasrc']; ?>)'></div>";
        <?php
                } while ($img_rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($img_query));
        ?>


        var w = 1, html = '', limitItem = 9;
        for (var i = 0; i < limitItem; ++i) {
            w = 200 +  200 * Math.random() << 0;
            html += temp.replace(/\{height\}/g, 200).replace(/\{width\}/g, w);
        }


        $("#freewall").html(html);

        var wall = new Freewall("#freewall");
        wall.reset({
            selector: '.cell',
            animate: true,
            cellW: 20,
            cellH: 200,
            onResize: function() {
                wall.fitWidth();
            }
        });
        wall.fitWidth();
        // for scroll bar appear;
        $(window).trigger("resize");
</script>
```

Does anyone know how to do that correctly? I don't know how to solve that problem.
Thx guys!

Comment: What does your database query look like ?

Comment: Please don't merge JS and PHP like this, use ajax requests instead.

Comment: that do/while loop is rather pointless. why have a loop to continually assign a bunch of html to one variable? You'll end up with a long series of `var temp = ` lines and only the LAST one of those will be of any use.

Comment: @Maximus2012 updated the original post

Comment: Please update your question with this information.

Comment: @MarcB, Ok but how shall I solve it? I mean I need to pull out 9 images from the db and append them to the div containers. I don't know the answer, sorry, not an expert – it's the first time I'm doing dynamic stuff like that.

Comment: @Yan I would first make sure that the query itself is giving you the correct result (Try executing it in PHPMyAdmin or MySQL Workbench etc.)

Comment: @Maximus2012 The query works, I'm using the exact same code (different column and table names though) to pull other stuff from the database. That works without any problems. I think the mistake is that the js is not following the php {do} ...

Comment: You should probably declare `temp` variable separately and then just add to it in the php while loop using `temp += `.

Comment: @Maximus2012 Got an example how? I've made several attempts, didn't work for me :-/

Comment: @Yan please take a look at the answer I posted. It may not be a complete solution as something else in your code might not be working. But that is the only way I can give you an example since that would be too much for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are iterating through the MySQL query, your variable is getting overwritten over and over again. Try replacing this part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php do {
    ?>
            var temp= "<div class='cell' style='width:{width}px; height: {height}px; background-image: url(<?php echo $img_rs['mediasrc']; ?>)'></div>";
    <?php
            } while ($img_rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($img_query));
    ?>
```

with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var temp;     /* declare temp variable first */
    <?php 
    while ($img_rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($img_query)){
    ?>
        /* add to the value of the temp variable while iterating through
         query result rather than overwriting the value */
        temp += "<div class='cell' style='width:{width}px; height: {height}px; background-image: url('<?php echo $img_rs['mediasrc']; ?>')></div>";
    <?php
    }
    ?>

    /* code after this part remains unchanged */
```

As mentioned in the comments, it may not be a good idea to mix and match PHP and JS like this. See if the above change works for you.

Comment: I am not entirely sure about the correctness of the syntax of the image div. I copied it as it is from the original question.

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work how I've tried the code. I don't really know how to get the dynamic img source inside the style attribute background-image: url(***database value goes here***) But thanks for your help though!

Comment: I would try looking at the page source to see what is the HTML getting generated. If this does not work then you can take the AJAX approach. That should be cleaner as well.

Comment: `<div class="cell" style="width: 205.85px; height: 185.77px; background-image: url/images/img1.jpg); position: absolute; opacity: 1; top: 0px; left: 0px; -webkit-transition: top 0.5s, left 0.5s, width 0.5s, height 0.5s, opacity 0.5s; transition: top 0.5s, left 0.5s, width 0.5s, height 0.5s, opacity 0.5s;" data-delay="1" data-height="200" data-width="202" data-state="move" id="1-2"></div>` the generated code looks fine, like I've said, the problem is that only the first image gets rendered

Comment: Try getting rid of this `{ $img_rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($img_query); }` (This is when you are executing the query statement)

Comment: Additionally,  in order to make things simple, try removing the css for that div and move it to a css class or something.